# prevent autoUpdate and autoCreateSlugs in TYPO3 10

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

is there a possibility to prevent the creating of updated Slugs and the automatic creating of redirects when renaming pages?

Background: I have to replace an old branch in the page tree with a new branch with the same page names and slugs. When i first rename the old branch and then rename the new branch to the name of the old branch i get one hell of wrong redirects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... there is a solution. After changing the slugs one get a blue notice in the top right corner of the window. In this window there are two links:

- reset the slugs of all subpages to their previous values
- delete all redirects

The notice with this links vanishes with the next action, so you do have only one try. But it fixed my problem.

--

An important reminder to read really every messages very carefull even if is only a hint ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an extension setting for EXT:redirects

```
autoCreateRedirects: false
autoUpdateSlugs: false
```